# Replacing carpet with laminate flooring - can I cover over damaged area?

Tags: flooring, carpet, laminate-floor, damage

I’ve decided to change from carpet (rug) to laminate flooring. There is a spot with some damage, near a vent. The damaged section has about a million nails in it so I want to leave it there.

I was thinking of adding a thin 1/8” ply layer to it which will also bring it up a little and make up a little for the rug that was there. The carpet has got underlay and carpet tack grippers at the edges.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you talking about a movable rug which covers some part of the floor, or a fixed-in-place carpet which covers the whole floor?

Comment: No it’s Got the underlay and the carpet tack grippers at the ends.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you.

Comment: A spot of what? What has a million nails in it? Please edit your post to be more clear.